# Iterate pyspark dataframe rows and apply UDF

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe that looks like this:
partitionCol orderCol valueCol

```
+--------------+----------+----------+
| partitionCol | orderCol | valueCol |
+--------------+----------+----------+
| A            | 1        | 201      |
| A            | 2        | 645      |
| A            | 3        | 302      |
| B            | 1        | 335      |
| B            | 2        | 834      |
+--------------+----------+----------+
```

I want to group by the partitionCol, then within each partition to iterate over the rows, ordered by orderCol and apply some function to calculate a new column based on the valueCol and a cached value.
e.g.

```py
def foo(col_value, cached_value):
    tmp = <some value based on a condition between col_value and cached_value>
    <update the cached_value using some logic>
    return tmp
```

I understand I need to groupby the partitionCol and apply a UDF that will operate on each chink separately, but struggling to find a good way to iterate the rows and applying the logic I described, to get a desired output of:

```
+--------------+----------+----------+---------------+
| partitionCol | orderCol | valueCol | calculatedCol -
+--------------+----------+----------+---------------+
| A            | 1        | 201      | C1            |
| A            | 2        | 645      | C1            |
| A            | 3        | 302      | C2            |
| B            | 1        | 335      | C1            |
| B            | 2        | 834      | C2            |
+--------------+----------+----------+---------------+
```

Comment: you need to explain `<update the cached_value using some logic>` because there are probably already the built-in functions you need but without knowing, it is difficult to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way for you to do that is to apply an UDF on the whole set of data :

```py
# first, you create a struct with the order col and the valu col
df = df.withColumn("my_data", F.struct(F.col('orderCol'), F.col('valueCol'))

# then you create an array of that new column 
df = df.groupBy("partitionCol").agg(F.collect_list('my_data').alias("my_data")

# finaly, you apply your function on that array
df = df.withColumn("calculatedCol", my_udf(F.col("my_data"))
```

But without knowing exactly what you want to do, that is all I can offer.

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks a lot for your answer! my exact problem is as follows. I have a table with userId, lat, lon, timestamp. For each user I want to group together events that are close in terms of both distance and time (aka spatiotemporal clustering). my desired final output is: userId, lat, lon, timeFrom, timeTo. In my question I was trying to obtain a helper dataframe in the structure of: userId, lat, lon, time, clusterNum. I hope it helps to clear things up. Thanks again!

Comment: If you have three events, A, B and C. A is close to B and B is close to C. But A and C are not that close ... do you group the three events ?

Comment: it's a methodology question that I want to examine. for now, I consider either averaging events location in the same cluster and then comparing new events to that average, or just compare with the first event. it's worth mentioning that I've already implemented this in python for prototype purposes and it works great, except it doesn't scale up. I'm also considering an option to use pandas_udf (as I've done in a previous project), but I suspect it will hurt performance.

Comment: @Gal175 Then the only solution I see is what I offered already. You collect, and manipulate with Python or pandas in UDF.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a go then. Thanks